Trying to use Query<> command sqlite c# using sqlite-net-pcl but it doesn't run
I have the following method which is inside a database context class for a .NET MAUI project. I have tested the SQL query in a DBMS without an error, so know it should be working. Using Debug.WriteLine I have come to the conclusion that the call to connection.Query<> is the issue, but can't find anything online/in documentation about why.
public List<ExerciseDetail> LoadSessionData(int sessionID)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"----dbStuff.LoadSessionData is called with sessionID: {sessionID}");

    // SQL query to fetch data
    var sql = @"
    SELECT e.ExerciseName,
            s.Repetitions AS Reps,
            s.Weight,
            s.Duration,
            s.Distance
    FROM Sets s
    JOIN Exercises e ON s.ExerciseID = e.ExerciseID
    WHERE s.SessionID = ?";

    // The following line gets printed:
    Debug.WriteLine($"----Executing SQL query: {sql}");

    // Execute the query with parameter sessionID
    var results = connection.Query<ExerciseSetDetail>(sql, sessionID);

    // The following line is never printed:
    Debug.WriteLine($"----Query executed successfully. Rows returned: {results.Count()}");

    // Process results to group by ExerciseName and collect details
    var groupedResults = results
        .GroupBy(r => r.ExerciseName)
        .Select(g => new ExerciseDetail
        {
            ExerciseName = g.Key,
            Sets = g.Select(x => new SetDetails
            {
                Reps = (int?)x.Reps,
                Weight = (int?)x.Weight,
                Duration = (int?)x.Duration,
                Distance = (double?)x.Distance
            }).ToList<SetDetails>()
        }).ToList();

    Debug.WriteLine($"----Reach after grouping");
    return groupedResults;
}

I have the class:
public class ExerciseSetDetail
{
    public string ExerciseName { get; set; }
    public int? Reps { get; set; }
    public double? Weight { get; set; }
    public int? Duration { get; set; }
    public double? Distance { get; set; }
}

which I made for the Query<> as I was originally doing Query<dynamic> which also didn't work.
My connection happens at the start of the database context:
public dbStuff()
{
    string dbPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "AppDatabase.db");
    CheckDB(dbPath);

    connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
    
}

private void CheckDB(string dbPath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(dbPath))
    {
        CopyDatabaseFromResource(dbPath);
    }
}

private void CopyDatabaseFromResource(string dbPath)
{
    var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(App)).Assembly;
    using (Stream? stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("GymAppProject.Resources.Database.AppDatabase.db"))
    {
        if (stream == null)
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Embedded database not found in the assembly resources.");
        }

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(dbPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            
        }
    }
}

I have tried to do the Query<dynamic> which gave the same results. One thing I was yet to try was make a new object of SQLConnection, but it seemed pointless as I already have a connection and have got data out of tables using said connection already, albeit not querying like this.

When you say "connection.Query<> is the issue" and "didn't work", what do you mean by that? Do you get an error, no data, or does the call to Query<>() never return?

Sorry, It never returns. I included 2 debug lines either side of connection.Query<>, i get the first to indicate it should be executing outputted but the second to indicate it successfully executed never writes to the output box, so I imagine it gets stuck in that statement

If a select query as simple as yours never returns, the problem is usually related to the database being locked. For example by a transaction or a PENDING or EXCLUSIVE lock from insert/delete/update. May be an external editor tool where you clicked in a line that triggers an "edit" mode, may be a different part of your code where you forgot to Dispose a reader or query object etc.

Or it is a hidden exception (Query throws but somewhere higher up in the callstack the exception is caught and dismissed silently, e.g. a _ = Task.Run(MyMethod) setup). Try wrapping the call to Query in a try { } catch (Exception e) { Debug.WriteLine(e); } to see if something is thrown.
